# Can and will C# write objects to the pagefile?

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory

I was wondering if it is possible for C# to write objects to the pagefile.

I already know that a virtual machine for a .NET application is limited to allow one object to only use up 2 GB of ram and will run out of Memory long before that - even on 64-bit version of Windows.

However I need to be able to load a huge amount of strings (not 1 big one but many small ones) and was wondering if it is possible to load them and let them be written to the swap space until they are needed again (unfortunately it is not possible for me to prevent the loading of all the strings because it is forced by an application calling the code I am working on).

To prototype it I tried out to see if the following program will run out of memory as well (which it will), even though it does not try to allocate one huge string:

```
public static void Main()
{
        ICollection<StringBuilder> builders = new LinkedList<StringBuilder>();
        double used_ram = 2*1024*1024*1024L;
        int blocksize = 12800000;
        int blocks = (int) (used_ram/blocksize);
        for (int i = 1; i < blocks ; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(blocksize/2);
            builders.Add(sb);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I was hoping that the strings would be written to the swap space and was wondering if there is any way I can force the application to do just that.

EDIT: Changed the use of swap file to pagefile (thanks for the clarifications).

Ok so to enhance my question: if the only limitation of the runtime is that ONE object can not allocate more than 2 gb of memory - why is the above code running out of memory - because the list goes over the 2 gb of memory by holding reference to all the string builders?

Comment: "writing to swap" isn't something applications do, it's something the OS does to applications. If your app/environment is limited to a 2G address space, no amount of "swap" will increase that.

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I expected - I think I really should look into basics of memory-management to really grasp all these concepts. So there is no way to get more space allocated by the runtime? Then I will probably have to write the strings to a file or something to store them till they are needed.

Comment: Swapping went out of style in the '70s. Nowadays virtual memory systems do "paging". In Windows, virtual memory is paged to the "pagefile".

Comment: This smells of pre-mature optimization

Comment: @Gjallar - Please also learn the correct terms for that platform you will be using.  If I am not mistaken a .Net application CAN use more then 2GB of memory.  So what exactly is you question?

Comment: 64-bit .Net applications *can* use much more than 2GB of virtual address space.

Comment: Yeah, unless it's compiled for x86 and run using WOW64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no you can't.

Using the swap is not something applications do: the memory management system of the operating system is responsible of that.

If you need to load more than 2GB of data in your process in one time (and not retrieve data from disk per chunks as necessary), then you have a serious design problem.

---

*EDIT*:
As you're already using a 64-bit OS, make sure you're compiling your application for x64 platforms (or AnyCPU) and your application is not running as a 32-bit process using WOW64.

Comment: I would say that it really depends on the application one is writing.  In many cases it could be a design problem, but sometimes there is an actual need to load very large amounts of data into memory.

Comment: Well I can't really discuss the system's design as I am fairily new to the team and am still trying to come to grasps with the system - but this was one of the first problems I was told to look into, so I guess a redesign is slightly out of my authorization level.

Comment: @Kibbee I agree that some applications really need to load more than 2GB of data. But in this particular case of the OP (many small strings), I really think it's a bad design.

Comment: @Gjallar: then you could move to 64-bit (which provides a larger addressable memory space) and ask your boss for 16GB or RAM ;-)

Comment: @Gjallar See updated answer as you're already using a 64-bit OS

Comment: Well that was it - the standard configuration was running as a 32-bit application running via WOW64. Changing it to a 64-bit target solved the mistery about why the example code runs out of memory. In case of the real application I will probably resort to a database or a cache file, because I simply have to handle the amount of strings somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question amount to:

> Can a 32 bit .NET application address more than 2GB of memory.

Yes, it is possible to increase the amount of memory that applications can address by adjusting the split between the memory allocated to user applications and the operating system but I would not recommend it in most cases as it can cause subtle and not so subtle problems with O/S functions, such as networking. For details on the `/3GB` and `/USERVA` switches please see [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/03/23/memory-management-demystifying-3gb.aspx). This will allow your application to address 3GB (minus overhead) of memory rather than 2GB.

Tools at your disposal are:

- Switching to 64 bit .NET.
- Using memory mapped files.
- Writing your own paging system.
- Using some backing store e.g. file system, database.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize all of the windows memory management functions and allocate as much memory as the system will allow, but what you are doing screams for some type of flush to disk system.  Even if you could get windows to allocate that large an object you performance would be terrible.  There are many out of the box system (called databases) which allow you to put large amounts of data in them and access them it very short order.

Comment: Yes something like that was what I was already thinking about - I am just wondering why the system runs out of memory when all the objects I allocate by themselves are well UNDER the limit of 2 gb per object as well (that's why I posted the small example as well - I think I did not make that clear enough in the question - sorry).

Comment: It runs out due to the way OS's manage memory.  Even under optimal conditions 2gb is a very large chunk of memory, and it will be paged no matter what you do.  Its just not a process you have controll of

Answer (score 1):

You may be doing something wrong. I've written .net applications that use way over 2 GB of memory. If you are running 64 bit windows, there's no reason your application shouldn't be able to use much more memory.

Comment: Ok then I guess my small example is running out of memory because the List keeps the references to all the string builders?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. You only have about 167 blocks by my calculations.  Storing that many entries in your linked list shouldn't create too many problems.  It doesn't store copies of the string builders, just references to them.  If you have a profiler available you should use that to see where all your memory is going.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you should write your own Cache-Class. For an example have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think what cames closes to your approach on the .Net application level would be a [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx).

But this would mean the application wouldn't try to get all the strings in one go.